# Unable to use USB 2.0 Sandisk 8 GB flash drive on android device and samsung HD TV

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, android

I formatted my USB 2.0 Sandisk 8 GB flash drive on windows 10 home edition as a local user (not administrator), after that I was able to open files as that user only. Not even administrator can open files on that drive. Now I am not able to mount that drive on my android 4.2.2(KitKat) tab and Samsung HD TV doesn't show any files on it.
I even had it quick formatted on windows 7 PC but still the problem persists.
Now I want to be able to use it on all devices as before, so please help in this issue.

Comment: I am not able to open video files as administrator on E: drive which I can do as a local user

Comment: You can edit your own question rather than adding details as comments.

Comment: Also, what filesystem did you select when you formatted it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably formatted your flash drive as `NTFS` file system. To allow other users to access files stored on this flash drive you have to change security permissions by granting full access to everyone group and recursively apply this permissions.

IMO better approach would be to save stored files and reformat flash drive to `exFAT` file system. It is more compatible standard that allows to read your flash drive practically on all platforms and it doesn't care about ACL permissions.